# laravel form is not submitted

Tags: laravel, routes

I am new to laravel. This is my view (bids.new):

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('bids.storeBid', $project->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
        @csrf

  *content*

     <div class="row pt-4">
           <button class="btn btn-primary">Place Bid</button>
     </div>

</form>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/bids/new/{id}', 'BidController@create')->name('bids.new');
Route::post('/bids/{id}', 'BidController@storeBid')->name('bids.storeBid');
```

BidController:

```
public function create($id)
{
    $project = Projects::findOrFail($id);
    return view('bids.new',compact('project'));
}
public function storeBid(Request $request, $id)
{
    *content*
}
```

When I clicked on Place Bid button in my view, the page is not responding and URL is still showing /bids/new/1 which means the storeBid route was not loaded. I tried using dd($id) at controller but it is not displaying as well so I assumed I have a problem with the route or form in the view.

Comment: Add button `type="submit"`

Comment: @MikeRoss hi added that but it's not working too

Comment: Not sure if it is the main problem, but that's not [how you specify parameters with named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes).

Comment: `action="{{ route('bids.storeBid', ['id' => $project->id]) }}"`

Comment: @stokoe0990 hi my way of passing the id is working in my other forms actually. I tried your way of specifying the parameter but it's still the same :(

Comment: is it because POST route does not pass parameter?

Comment: actually I'm passing this project_id because it is the foreign key of bid table. Is there any other way of saving the foreign key without passing it as parameter?

Comment: If the form is not even submitting, it is an HTML problem. Does the rendered HTML look OK?  Try creating a super-simplified version of your form, in plain HTML, no Blade/PHP, just hard-coded plain text HTML.  Does it work?  What does your browser devtools show?

Comment: You're using `multipart/form-data` ... is there any form of upload functionality in your form? if yes, this might be a cause of why it seems like the form is not working since it's trying to upload the file

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row pt-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place Bid</button>
</div>
```

try this one. I hope it will help you. Let me know.

Comment: hi thanks for replying. I tried it but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the comments, I figured out the problem was not because of the form or route but due to some errors on my eloquent in the controllers.